# 2 RequestMapping with the same path but different path variables. Would that work?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Simple question. Would this work. Is Spring smart enough to resolve that the pathvariable type is different and use the appropriate one:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/get/{criteria}")
public ResponseEntity<CrudPage<Object>> getAll(@PathVariable ICrudCriteria criteria);

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/get/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<T> getOneById(@PathVariable Long id);
```

Comment: Why don't you try it out ;)

Comment: What is ICrudCriteria? You cannot use objects in an URL

Comment: of course you can. Long is also an object btw